# How to save t.test result in R to a txt file?

Tags: r

I have got an output like this( t test output)

[image]

I want to combine them. But it came like this. Values are same only but not in the above format.
[image]

How can we save all of them in a txt format in the first mentioned format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `capture.output` to print the objects and save the output into a character vector:

```
chars <- capture.output(print(t_SVI_Chennai), print(t_SVI_Mumbai))
```

You can then write it to a file with `writeLines`, such as:

```
writeLines(chars, con = file("output.txt"))
```